# Multiple tableviews using a shared datasource but varying number of rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a couple of tableviews in my app that use one instance of a datasource called TaskListDataSource class that conforms to UITableViewDataSource

```
class TaskListDataSource: NSObject {
    typealias TaskCompletedAction = () -> Void
    
    private var tasks: [Task] = SampleData.tasks
    private var taskCompletedAction: TaskCompletedAction?
    
    init(taskCompletedAction: @escaping TaskCompletedAction) {
        self.taskCompletedAction = taskCompletedAction
        super.init()
    }
}

extension TaskListDataSource: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tasks.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell", for: indexPath) as? TaskCell else {
            fatalError("Unable to dequeue TaskCell")
        }
        cell.configure(task: tasks[indexPath.row]) {
            self.tasks[indexPath.row].completed.toggle()
            self.taskCompletedAction?()
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

I pass in the instance via dependency injection and set the tableview datasource like so. I do this for all my view controllers that use this datasource object.

```
var taskListDataSource: TaskListDataSource
    
init?(coder: NSCoder, taskListDataSource: TaskListDataSource) {
    self.taskListDataSource = taskListDataSource
    super.init(coder: coder)
}
    
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TaskCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "taskCell")
    tableView.dataSource = taskListDataSource
}
```

however I would like to implement a way so that on one of the UITableViewControllers the number of rows is limited to 3 rows. At the moment because of following code snippet it will always just display the total amount of tasks in the tasks array.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tasks.count
}
```

On each tableview it shows the total amount of tasks but I want a way in which I can somehow keep the reusability of the cellForRowAt function but make the numberOfRows function dynamic.

Comment: Add a property to `TaskListDataSource`, to know if you should "should limit to 3" (or less if there are less tasks) and check that value in `numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: @Larme Because I only have one instance of this TaskListDataSource, this property will need to be updated every time the user views a new tableview. So I would have to continuously set the property and reload the tableview in viewDidAppear. Would there be a cleaner approach than this?

Comment: Probably the best thing to do is to split your class. One part takes care of holding the data (e.g. TaskListDataStore) and is a single instance and another part takes care of displaying the data (TaskListDataSource). From `TaskListDataSource` you could then create an instance for each controller.

Comment: @Johannes Starke I like this a lot. It works well with a generic model store class I created. So I would inject that store into each controller and feed it through each initializer of a TaskListDataSource object. When changes are made however how would I keep all tableview UI in sync? (E.g. task checkbox that indicates if it’s completed or not)

Comment: In most cases it should be enough if you reload the data in viewWillAppear, right? Otherwise you could also add a classic delegate (or callback) to your store so that the ViewController can register for changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a dictionary to save the limit of each tableview

```
    ...
    private maxRows: [String: Int?] = [:]
    ...
```

add a function to handle the binding datasource

```
    ...
    func add(_ tableView: UITableView, maxRows: Int? = nil) {
        if let id = tableView.id {
            self.maxRows[id] = maxRows
        }
        tableView.datasource = self
    }
    ...
```

then the datasoure function numberOfRowsInSection become

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let id = tableView.id {
              return maxRows[id] ?? tasks.count
        }
        return tasks.count
}
```

and set the tableview datasource like

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TaskCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "taskCell")
    taskListDataSource.add(tableView, maxRow: 3) 
}
```

`tableView.id` could be whatever you want. ex: you subclass UITableView and add a property

```
class UITableViewWithID: UITableView {
    var id: String?
}
```

Comment: I decided to use your concept of identifying and added the following to the numberOfRows function `return tableView.accessibilityIdentifier == "ReviewViewController" ? tasks.count : 3`